# Symbol for set of all polynomials of certain degree

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

The symbol I am looking for is something like a curvy P, where P_n(F) represents the set of all polynomials with coefficients in F and degree equal to or less than n.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I use something like `\mathcal{P}_n(F)`, but meaning the set of polynomials with degree *less* than *n* (which so is a vector space of dimension *n*, for all *n* ≥ 0). I've never understood why people use the wrong indexing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use: `$\mathcal{P}_n(F)$`

Or more writing style using package `mathrsfs`: `$\mathscr{P}_n(F)$`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P}_n(F)$

$\mathscr{P}_n(F)$
\end{document}
```

Output result:

[image: Output]

Comment: Note that `\mathscr` requires a specific package.

Comment: @egreg : I'll edit my answer to add it

Comment: Providing an MWE and an output image with your answer is also helpful to readers.